# Postgres custom type with constraints

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, postgresql-12

I was wondering if it were possible (and/or desirable) to create custom types with constraints on the values. Say I have a custom type for height/width/length:

`CREATE TYPE dimensions AS (w float, h float, l float);`

I'd like to ensure that none of my widths are greater than 10 (for example).

Is such a thing possible, or would I be better served creating check constraints on every table that uses this type? I'd like to be able to add/edit the constraint in a single place (ie, on the type itself).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a [domain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdomain.html) based on your type.

```
create domain checked_dimensions 
   as dimensions
   constraint check_size check ( (value).w <= 10 );
```

Note the parentheses around the keyword `value`. They look redundant but are required in this case.

Then use the type `checked_dimensions` as your column type

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Schema Error: error: "dimensions" is not a valid base type for a domain